# Conditional load a component in React based on right click

Tags: reactjs, right-click

Any tips on creating a component on right click in React?
Here is an example

```
  export const ItemControl: React.FC<ItemControlProps> = ({ someprops }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <otherComponents />
            <RightClickContextMenu item={item} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

The ItemControl is used inside a long list which creates lots of RightClickContenxtMenu per item and adds ton of time to JS processing. Assuming I don't want to lazy load it and rather conditionally load it.
1- How can I either conditionally create this on rightclick only?
2- Is there a way I can create this RightClickContextMenu once and share/use it across all items?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [react-contextify?](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-contexify)

Comment: I have the contextMenu, I would like to handle the creation/render it condtionally. Not sure how this will help